# TSQL Including fiscal year in select statement based on the date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I need to include the fiscal year in my select statement based on today's date e.g for 12/30/2016 2016-2017. The fiscal year starts as of July 1. As of July 1,2017 it should calculate 2017-2018. How can I accomplish that?

```
ClaimNo
20161030
20161124
20160815
20170115
20180101

SELECT * 
FROM TABLE
WHERE ClaimNo LIKE '2016%' OR ClaimNo LIKE '2017%';
```

Comment: Do you want to include the fiscal year in the `SELECT`, i.e. create another column with the fiscal year, or restrict the rows returned by fiscal year, e.g. `WHERE FiscalYear( ClaimNo ) = 1066`? Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @ThisYear VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @NextYear VARCHAR(50)
SET @ThisYear = CAST(DATEPART(YYYY,GETDATE()) as varchar(20)) +'0731'  --print @ThisYear
SET @NextYear = CAST(DATEPART(YYYY,DATEADD(YYYY,1,GETDATE()))as varchar(20))+'1231' --print @Nextyear


SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE CAST(ClaimNo AS DATE) BETWEEN @ThisYear and @NextYear
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ClaimNo,
    CASE WHEN MONTH(CONVERT(DATE,ClaimNo)) <7 THEN YEAR(CONVERT(DATE,ClaimNo))
        ELSE YEAR(CONVERT(DATE,ClaimNo)) + 1 END AS FiscalYear
FROM
    <<Table>>;
```

---

Test Code

```
DECLARE @tab TABLE (ClaimNo CHAR(20));

INSERT INTO @tab (ClaimNo)
VALUES
('20161030'),
('20161124'),
('20160815'),
('20170115'),
('20180101');

SELECT ClaimNo,
    CASE WHEN MONTH(CONVERT(DATE,ClaimNo)) <7 THEN YEAR(CONVERT(DATE,ClaimNo))
        ELSE YEAR(CONVERT(DATE,ClaimNo)) + 1 END AS FiscalYear
FROM
    @tab;
```

Answer (score 1):

With the help of an ad-hoc tally table, we can easily calculate the the Fiscal Year.  In this case, we are starting at 1980 and for the next 50 years.  Both items can be tweaked as necessary.

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (ClaimNo varchar(25));
INSERT INTO @table (ClaimNo)
VALUES
('20161030'),
('20161124'),
('20160815'),
('20170115'),
('20180101');


Select A.ClaimNo
      ,FiscalYear = Str(Year(D1),4)+' - '+Str(Year(D2),4)
 From  @table A
 Join (
        Select Top 50 D1=cast(DateAdd(YY,Row_Number() Over (Order By Number)-1,'1980-07-01') as Date) 
                     ,D2=cast(DateAdd(YY,Row_Number() Over (Order By Number),'1980-06-30') as Date) 
         From master..spt_values 
      ) D
    on ClaimNo Between D1 and D2
```

Returns

```
ClaimNo     FiscalYear
20161030    2016 - 2017
20161124    2016 - 2017
20160815    2016 - 2017
20170115    2016 - 2017
20180101    2017 - 2018
```

Note:  If ClaimNo is an int, just change the ON clause to

```
on cast(ClaimNo as varchar(8)) Between D1 and D2
```